# Binding in RichTextBox Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a Binding to the Run'Text property . I am binding to a single class property. Below are the code and samples :

the xaml code:

```
 <Grid>
    <RichTextBox>
        <RichTextBox.Document>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph >
                    <Run Text="{Binding TestText,Mode=TwoWay}"></Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox.Document>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

the code behind code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        this.PropertyChanged += MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
    }


    private string text = "TestText";

    public string TestText
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text == value) return;
            text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TestText");
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TestText);
    }


    #region NotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

when I input 1,2,3,4,5 
I get the "5" instead of "5Te4st3Te2xt1"

[image]

Comment: What are you doing to get the application to write to a Console (within MainWindow_PropertyChanged)? This may be a red-herring, so I replaced your code with Debug.WriteLine to see what is going on...

Further, it is not clear what you mean by "... input 1,2,3,4,5". From your comment about "... instead of 5Te4st3Te2xt1", I'm guessing that you are inserting the digits one at a time in the appropriate positions within the text "TestText"

With VS 2015  + Win10 + .NET 4.6.1, unable to reproduce your problem. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/1E65W.png

Comment: mine is vs2015+update 1 +win10 +.net4.0

Comment: @Vatsan your output for 5 times and I output for ten times . your code behind is same to me?

Comment: @MsYvette NO , I just want to keep the RichTextBox Text same to the TestText property

Comment: yes ,  I want  to  binding some Run to my entity's property. and when the user modify the value in RichTextBox. My program can get the modified value in time

Comment: @R.Wei  - Yes, my code-behind is exactly the same as yours. You didn't explain how you were getting Console wired up with a WPF application... You should consider writing a WPF project (without attaching it to a Console), use Debug.WriteLine and see where that takes you.

Comment: I use console , just want print the output. the key is when I input a character,the method (OnPropertyChanged) trigger twice. the first I get the wanted value, the second ,I get the value that was cut off

Comment: @R.Wei - When you say .net4.0, I'll assume that is your Target framework version. Win10 ships with .NET 4.6 and you can't be using an older runtime version. I changed my project to target .NET 4.0, and I still cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Vatsan  I'll try it in another pc.

Comment: the question stil exists @Vatsan

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBoxes` are not particularly suited for this. The user could just delete your text completely and the binding will be gone. There also is no telling what it does if you insert text; it may as well split your `Run` (creating a new one after the insertion point) and append to the former. In fact, that is exactly what your output seems to indicate here.

To be sure you will want to inspect the whole document structure. In any case: I would not recommend trying to bind a `RichTextBox` at all. Writing your own component or using an existing library that expressly has binding support is probably the way to go.